# Integer passing in url

Tags: ios

Hi in my json result the keyvalue is in integer and I need to pass integer in `Url.my keyvalue` is @"Id".. if i pass `CategoryId=112` I get result but it is hardcored where I need to pass this dynamically.

Please help me out.

```
  -(void)WebServiceTopic{

   // [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];

    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *TopicManager=[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

    AFJSONRequestSerializer*serializer=[AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];

    [serializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content"];

    [serializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];

    TopicManager.requestSerializer=serializer;

    NSString *Postlink = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@Discussions/%@/?categoryId",PUBLICURL, [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]valueForKey:@"USERID"]];

    NSLog(@"Link is %@",Postlink);


    [TopicManager GET:Postlink parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject){

        NSLog(@"JSON:%@", responseObject);

        NSDictionary *userDict=(NSDictionary *)responseObject;

        Topic = (NSMutableArray*)userDict;
        [TopicTable reloadData];

    }failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"the failure is %@", error);

      //  [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];

    }];
}
```

Comment: In which line  you are adding static "CategoryId=112" ?

Comment: in nsString *postlink

Comment: see my answer please

Answer (score 0):

If You are looking for an array of objects. So, you create a blank array. Create an object for each input by using 'title' and 'email' as keys. Then you add each of the objects to the array.

If you need a string, then do

```
jsonString = JSON.stringify(jsonObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass it dynamically using the parameter. like below,

```
[manager GET:main_url parameters:parameters success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject)
```

Note:
    I am using php script so i can pass the values as parameter (NSDictionary).

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *Postlink = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@Discussions/%@/?categoryId=%d",PUBLICURL, [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]valueForKey:@"USERID"]], [[dic objectForKey:@"Id"] intValue]];
```

Where **dic** is your result json and **"Id"** is key. 
Feel free to comment if you have any confusion.

Comment: please check this url...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34433032/passing-keyvalue-from-one-viewcontroller-to-another-from-json-webservice @Mukesh Chaudhary

Comment: Its not coming bro.please check my link for detailed analysis